# ¿Como exportar base de datos realizada en Mongodb a VPS en digital ocean?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, vps

tengo un problema con la exportacion de la base de datos, He venido desarrollando un sistema (MEAN), y lo hemos usado en una intranet, todo perfecto hasta ahi, Ahora estamos contratando un VPS y casi todo ya esta configurado, excepto la base de datos, lo que me falta es poder migrar desde mi servidor local hacia el VPS. Ya he realizado respaldos de mi base de datos en local (con mongodump y mongorestore), pero como subo toda mi base de datos hacia el VPS???

Ya busque en google y digitalocean ofrece un articulo para realizar importanciones y exportaciones de mongo. pero esta en formato .json, ademas de que solo es un documento. en mi caso mi base de datos esta en .bson y son muchas colleciones (una base datos completa en si).
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de esta manera, lo primero que hice fue comprimir el dump en un zip, posteriormente lo subi utilizando SCP mediante ssh. Ya en el servidor descomprimir el zip y restaurar el dump y listo.
Cada día, veo lo necesario y practico que es linux. Espero a alguien le sirva mi respuesta